# Get values from xml document with linqToXml

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I just can't get this figured out right. I've tried looking around but my queries won't render any results.

This is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Prices>
  <PricePerItem>
    <Item Name="Milk, Low fat, 1Liter">11.2</Item>
    <Item Name="Butter">17</Item>
    <Item Name="Bread">12.2</Item>
    <Item Name="Cheese">15.5</Item>
  </PricePerItem>
  <PricePerKg>
    <Item Name="Apple, Jonagold">13.4</Item>
    <Item Name="Chicken">12.5</Item>
    <Item Name="Salad">9.6</Item>
    <Item Name="Fish, Salmon">14</Item>
  </PricePerKg>
</Prices>
```

And my method (not done ofc)

```
private static Dictionary<string, int> GetPrizesFromXML()
{
    //Read the values from the XMLDoc
    XElement xml = XElement.Load("prices.xml");
    var prizes = from q in xml.Elements("Prices") 
                 select q.Elements("Item");
    foreach (var prize in prizes)
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine(prize.ToString());
    }

    return null;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this line:

```
var prizes = from q in xml.Elements("Prices") 
             select q.Elements("Item");
```

to this:

```
var prizes = from q in xml.Elements("Prices") 
             select q.Descendants("Item");
```

Comment: Sorry, couldn't upvote because of the old browser. Done it now though. Thanks!

Comment: @Phil please mark this as the answer by clicking on the checkmark if it worked for you.